# Picker in SwiftUI Form turns gray after selecting a value

Tags: swift, swiftui, ios14

For some reason the picker in my SwiftUI Form turns gray after I select a value.

My code:

```
Form {
  Section {
    TextField("title", text: $title)
      Picker(selection: $category, label: Text("category")) {
        ForEach(0..<categories.count) { index in
            Text(categories[index]).tag(index)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[image: Here is how it looks on a iPhone 12 simulator]

Comment: Not reproducible with Xcode 12.1 / iOS 14.1. Which env did you use?

Comment: Not reproducible with Xcode 12.3 / iOS 14.3 as well.

Comment: Have you tested it on a real device? I have occasionally seen this on the Simulator...

Comment: Yes, I tried it on an iPhone 11 under iOS 14, and still had the same issue

Comment: Also present for Menu as a default system behavior in MacOS. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65771764/override-menu-button-label-text-color-macos-swiftui?noredirect=1#comment116303246_65771764 Filed FB8974731

Answer (score 5):

You need to wrap your form inside a NavigationView, the reason being when you tap the picker it will bring up another page, so it needs the navigation view in order to be able to navigate back.

```
NavigationView {
  Form {
    Section {
      TextField("title", text: $title)
        Picker(selection: $category, label: Text("category")) {
          ForEach(0..<categories.count) { index in
              Text(categories[index]).tag(index)
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Didn't work. I'm already in a Navigation view and my pickers are still gray when I come back after making a selection.