# Override menu button label text color (MacOS SwiftUI)

Tags: macos, swiftui

Can I override a Menu button label's "post-set dimmed" color?

The GIF below shows a legibly bright menu item that dims after new selection. (Default behavior for this system style (e.g., in trackpad prefs).

But it fails accessibility standards, such as WCAG's requirement for > 4.5 : 1 luminance contrast for that font size in an active control (system default is ~ 2).

[image: Inactive menu color]

I've tried:

- setting `accentColor` and `foregroundColor` everywhere
- using `onChange` to update an @State color fed into the aforementioned modifiers
- using `onReceive` for `NSMenu.didSendActionNotification` or from calls to the delegate `menuDidClose` method (was hunting for some appearance setting)
- using the `DefaultMenuStyle`, not borderless
- ramping up `brightness` or `contrast`, but that introduces aliasing issues

Any suggestions? Maybe I'm just supposed to be using a Picker? Should I flag this as an accessibility issue with Apple?

```swift
struct BareExample: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        
        Menu { menuContents }
            label: { menuLabel }
            .menuStyle(BorderlessButtonMenuStyle())
            .fixedSize()
    }
    
    var menuContents: some View {
        ForEach(sortOptions) { option in
            Button(option.rawValue) { setSortOrder(option) }
                .accentColor(labelColor)
                .foregroundColor(labelColor)
        }
    }
    
    var menuLabel: some View {
        HStack {
            Image(systemName: sortIcon)
            Text(sortOrderLabel)
        }
        .accentColor(labelColor)
        .foregroundColor(labelColor)

    }
    
    @State var sortOrder: PaletteSortOrder = .sequential
    
    var sortOrderLabel: String { sortOrder.rawValue }
    
    let sortIcon = "arrow.up.arrow.down"
    let sortOptions = PaletteSortOrder.allCases
    @State var labelColor = Color.white
    
    func setSortOrder(_ order: PaletteSortOrder) {
        sortOrder = order
        labelColor = Color.white
    }
    
}

public enum PaletteSortOrder: String, CaseIterable, Identifiable {
    case sequential = "Sequential"
    case byLuminance = "Luminance"
    case byWorstPairwiseContrast = "Pairwise Contrast"
    
    public var id: String { rawValue }
}
```

Comment: This question is very similar to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65405759/picker-in-swiftui-form-turns-gray-after-selecting-a-value

Comment: I’ve seen this too, it appears to be a macOS bug. All we can do is send feedback to Apple and hope they fix it.

Comment: @Adam I've filed: FB8974731

Comment: still no good ?

Comment: I think Apple just does not want colored menu items on macOS. I've never seen that in any Cocoa or SwiftUI app...